# More Precision Number

Tags: rust, precision

I am learning Rust to develop crypto programmes, I tried many ways to get precision exact number but failed, here is my simple function

```
use rust_decimal::Decimal;

fn main() {
    let a = Decimal::new(5, 0);
    let b = Decimal::new(501, 7);
    let c = a + b;
    let d = a * b;
    let e = a - b;
    let f = a / b;
    let g = f.round_dp(7);

    println!("a + b = {}", c);
    println!("a * b = {}", d);
    println!("a - b = {}", e);
    println!("a / b = {}", f);
    println!("a / b (rounded to 7 decimal places) = {}", g);
}
```

Its output is:

```
a + b = 5.0000501
a * b = 0.0002505
a - b = 4.9999499
a / b = 99800.3992015968063872255489
a / b (rounded to 7 decimal places) = 99800.3992016
```

You can see the last statement is 99800.3992016 after converting it into 7 decimals but before of it was 99800.3992015.

I want to stop round figure and want exact number which does not have any 0.00000001 difference.

Comment: First of all: is that rust_decimal lib? If so, then it seems you are looking for `trunc_with_scale` fn instead of `round_dp`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, you are right it was ...0159 but I want to ignore all numbers which are out of my range. so I want to ignore "9" in above statement.

Comment: @freakish , yes it's a library for decimals, and it's very famous.Its imports the "Decimal" type from the "rust_decimal"

Answer (score 0):

The [`round_dp`](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/struct.Decimal.html#method.round_dp) function rounds the number and

> [...] currently follows “Bankers Rounding” rules. e.g. 6.5 -> 6, 7.5 -> 8

so it correctly rounds `...0159` to `...016`. If you want to truncate any remaining digits instead, you should use a function that rounds towards zero.

There is such a function: [`round_dp_with_strategy`](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/struct.Decimal.html#method.round_dp_with_strategy). The rounding strategy also exists: [`ToZero`](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/prelude/enum.RoundingStrategy.html#variant.ToZero).

So you could change your code to

```
let g = f.round_dp_with_strategy(7, RoundingStrategy::ToZero);
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what the difference is to `trunc_with_scale`. It might be a simpler alternative.

Comment: thanks, Its solves by using "round_dp_with_strategy"